# copy/paste functionality in fabric.js

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

In currently I have added code for copy and paste object in fabric js.But while selecting group of objects its not working. 
Is there any way to implement copy/paste functionality for group of objects on canvas with fabric.js framework?

here is my code for paste

```
pasteSelectedObjs: function() {
    cur_canvas = canvasObjArr[this.page];
    if (clipboard.length < 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (cur_canvas.getActiveObject()) {
        clipboard.set('active', true);
        cur_canvas.add(clipboard);
        cur_canvas.setActiveObject(clipboard);
    }
    clipboard = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got the proper solution.

```
if (cur_canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
    cur_canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    clipboard.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        obj.set('active', true);
        cur_canvas.add(obj);
    });
    cur_canvas.setActiveGroup(clipboard).renderAll();
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I did it. It checks if it's an object or group and that's it's not a path group - which wasn't happy about being cloned.

```
   /**
     * Will copy an object on the canvas
     */
    var copyObject;

    copy(){
        let o = canvas.getActiveObject();
        let t = o.get('type');

        if (o && t !== 'path-group'){
            let clone = o.clone();
            if (clone) {
                clone.set({
                    top: clone.top + 50,
                    left: clone.left + 50
                });
            }

            copyObject = clone;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will clone an object to the canvas
     */
    paste(){
        if (copyObject){
            canvas.add(copyObject);
            canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working perfect @Paul, but my issue is I want to copy/paste `group of objects`, here the issue is. But see my below code. It's working.